# How do i iterate through two lists with string elements in python with a condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example, I have two lists like

```
a = ["there", "is", "a", "car"]
b = ["i", "feel", "happy", "today"]
```

I want to compare `a[0]` and `b[0]1, if there is any common alphabet between`'there'`and`'i'` the result should be true or else it should be false

Output:

```
[False,False,True,True]
```

I was able to do it if it is just one element in a and b but cannot iterate through the list

```
a = ["there", "is", "a", "car" , "jill"]
b = ["i", "feel", "happy", "today" ,"jill"]
d = []
i = 0
for  word in range(len(a)):
    for word in range (len(b)):
        c = list(set(a[i]) & set(b[i]))
    if c == []:
            d.append(False)
    else:
            d.append(True)
i = i+1
print (d)
```

Comment: now that the question has been answered, and answers were voted on, I believe it would be a demonstration of good citizenship to either accept an answer or clarify why it cannot be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to perform the tests in pairs, this is your code:

```
print([bool(set(x) & set(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b)])
```

Your input lists are of unequal length, so it is not clear to me what you want to do with "jill" (the **b** item unmatched if **a**).

A bit more details:

- **zip** makes a list of pairs from a pair of lists (it actually makes a list of n-tuples from n lists, but in our case n == 2).
- As you figured, constructing a set from a string returns the set of characters in the string.
- **&** as a set operator is set intersection
- constructing a **bool** value from a set return that set's non-emptiness.
- Simple list comprehension constructs the result.

Comment: Thanks for the details Amitai

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
d = [len(set(i)&set(j)) > 0 for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Testing:

```
>>> a = ["there", "is", "a", "car" , "jill"]
>>> b = ["i", "feel", "happy", "today" ,"jill"]
>>> d = [len(set(i)&set(j)) > 0 for i,j in zip(a,b)]
>>> d
[False, False, True, True, True]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other's answers are good enough, here is your version fixed:

```
a = ["there", "is", "a", "car" , "jill"]
b = ["i", "feel", "happy", "today" ,"jill"]
d = []
i = 0
for  word in range(len(a)):
    for word in range (len(b)):
        c = list(set(a[i]) & set(b[i]))
    if c == []:
            d.append(False)
    else:
            d.append(True)
    i = i+1  # <------------------------ this was missing an indentation
print (d)
```